How to change app signing key for AppSheet app
I have an app that I am rebuilding in AppSheet and need to update my app signing key to get the Google Play to accept the new version.
The previous versions of the app were created by a freelance designer in Expo and uploaded to the Play Store for distribution. I'm not a developer. We needed to update the app, so I taught myself the AppSheet platform and made a new version of the app.
When I try to upload the new AppSheet-based version, I get the following error.
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprints):
SHA1:
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprints):
SHA1:

My understanding is that I need to generate a new app signing key that is somehow integrated into my AppSheet APK, so that Google Play will accept the new upload. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Emails to both AppSheet help and Google Play help don't seem to understand my problem enough to offer a fix.
I found this help article, but that seems to assume I'm using Android Studio for development.
Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm obviously not an ace with this stuff.
I've tried to upload the latest APK from AppSheet, but it fails. I'm not sure how to get the new signing key connected with my AppSheet APK.
